# Overwrite static function name using macros

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

i would like to make runtime measurements without modifying my original code (it is not mine actually), the code looks like this:

Code.c:

```
#define CODE_SOURCE
#include "GlobalInclude.h"
#include "Code.h"

unsigned int Add(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
  while(x--)
  {
    y++;
  }
  return y;
}
```

Code.h:

```
#ifndef CODE_H
#define CODE_H

unsigned int Add(unsigned int x, unsigned int y);

#endif
```

Main.c:

```
#include "GlobalInclude.h"
#include "Code.h"


int main()
{
  printf("5+6 = %d", Add(5,6));

  return 0;
}
```

GlobalInclude.h

```
#ifndef GLOBALINCLUDE_H
#define GLOBALINCLUDE_H

#if defined CODE_SOURCE
#define Add(x,y) Add_Custom(x,y)
#endif

#endif
```

Hereby, i overwrite the Add method with my own Add_Custom method and can do some runtime measurements, e.g.:

```
#define STUB_SOURCE
#include "GlobalInclude.h"
#include "Code.h"
#define DO_SOMETHING() 


unsigned int Add_Custom(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
  unsigned int result;
  DO_SOMETHING();
  result = Add(x,y);
  DO_SOMETHING();
  return result;  
}
```

My question is now, is it somehow possible with methods which are declared and defined in the c file(Code.c)? I did not find any possible solution for this.

Comment: To print a value of type `unsigned int` use `"%u"` in the printf format string, otherwise it's UB.

Comment: You may be able to do some "trickery" with the **linker**. I can't help with that, just wanted to give you another keyword to search for.

Comment: @pmg: Thank you for the idea with the linker. But actually I would like to have a somehow generic solution, which does not depend on specific tools (since each linker has its own possibilities and some might support these features, others not.

Answer (score 0):

In case of internal linkage/static, you can only write a "mock" function of a function existing inside the same translation unit. So either you have to modify the .c file or one of the headers included by that file.

The least disruptive might be to create a "mock.h" which you include from the C file, then add a macro like the one in your question there.

If the .c file and all included headers are to be regarded as read-only, then no, it isn't possible.

Comment: One can manipulate the GlobalInclude.h file, but not Code.[c/h].